# Create Update query by joining two tables with github.com/go-pg/pg

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I am trying to update one field in my postgres table by joining some conditions with another table. I referred [this link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-update-join/), which give me a query model that relates to my scenario:

```
UPDATE product as p SET price = 200 FROM  product_segment as ps WHERE p.segment_id = ps.id and p.name = 'diam'
```

Now I have to convert this query in to orm.Query. I tried with Join() but it doesn't seem to work .

the code I tried :

```
_, err := c.postgresDB.WithContext(ctx).Model(Product).
    Set("price =?", 200).
    Join("LEFT JOIN product_segment as ps").
    JoinOn("ps.id = product.segment_id").
    Where("name =?", "diam").
    Update()
```

How do I properly write the code to achieve desired result ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, I ended up doing the below code which gave me the result I wanted.

```
_, err := c.postgresDB.WithContext(ctx).Model(Product).
    Set("price =? from product_segment as ps", 200).
    Where("name =?", "diam").
    Update()
```

Please share if you guys have better methods.